# arabic query to google in .NET webbrowser

Tags: c#, character-encoding, browser, arabic

I have a .NET web browser and I use it to search query's in Google in this format:

```
webbrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com/search?q="+Query);
```

It works fine with English queries but when I use Arabic queries, I see question mark characters like:
??????

I tried this code but it wasn't helpful:

```
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
byte[] asciiArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, byteArray);
string finalString = ascii.GetString(asciiArray);
```

Comment: The problem is before that line. Where was `Query` from? The conversion code you pasted isn't helpful either. It creates more confusion.

Comment: I edited to change "C# Web Browser" to ".NET Web Browser". The web browser control is not part of C#. It's part of .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used google translate to find an arabic word. I hope it really means "test" :)

```
string query = "اختبار";
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?q="+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query));
```